# How do I write unit test for logic apps steps using Ms unit project c# code?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, azure, visual-studio-2015, azure-logic-apps

I have created a simple azure logic app.

- Step 1 - http request
- Step 2 - XML transformation
- Having map file xslt added for XML file
- Step 3- send transformation XML data into service bus queue.
- Step 4 - request response

I want to create above logic app unit test cases using msunit project. I'm new to logic apps.

Comment: Do you want to test it without deploy on Azure?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've dug quite a bit into the topic when was looking closely into Logic Apps... AFAIK, whether with or without deploying your Logic App to Azure, there's no way ***unit* test** a specific step, sorry.

At the very best you could have an ***end-to-end* / *integration* test**. That would require you to deploy the App into Azure cloud, because you don't have any other way to make your Logic App's JSON definition executable locally (on your desktop, or other on-premise machine).

Now we're talking about end-to-end tests, hence there's a question how do you make sure that your test does not mess up production data, right? This, in turn, raises one of two subsequent questions:

- How do I model environments/stages for Azure Logic Apps? or
- How do I write my tests to guarantee that prod data is intact and no garbage data is generated in production either?

(Hint: Even though, both problems are solvable, none of these ^ questions have simple-easy answers. I personally decided to *NOT* go that way at all).

---

To give you some hope. In case you are okay with diverging from pure Logic App based solution, I'd recommend into implementing your custom logic as Azure Functions. Those functions are just normal JavaScript/C#/language of choice code which you actually *can unit-test locally*. Those functions are also *easy to invoke* from a Logic App.

The Logic App as a platform may work well as an orchestrating platform. It supports multiple triggers; allows controlling the degree of parallelism in your application; it lets you configure retry and timeout logic; and so on. It's just not good at all when it comes to everything that's related to expressing application logic that deals with the connectors.

---

Related sources:

- **!!!** Slides with some decent ideas: [Automated Testing with Logic Apps and Specflow](https://www.slideshare.net/biztalk360/automated-testing-with-logic-apps-and-specflow?ref=http://www.integrationusergroup.com/automated-testing-logic-apps-specflow/)
- [StackOverflow: Can you have automated regression/integration tests for Azure Logic Apps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41852401/can-you-have-automated-regression-integration-tests-for-azure-logic-apps)
- [Is Your Serverless Application Testable? – Azure Logic Apps](https://blog.kloud.com.au/2017/07/24/is-your-serverless-application-testable-azure-logic-apps/)

Comment: Regarding the first bullet, there is a **major** problem with the suggested approach -- he suggests using Event Hub to capture the test events. There is a ~2-minute latency between event generation and it getting passed through to the Event Hub listener. Instead, you can call the Logic App API for execution history **immediately after execution completion** [(see this approach)](https://coffeefirst.dev/azure/how-to-test-a-logic-app/)

Answer (score 0):

The previous responses relate to Consumption logic apps that can only be deployed into an Azure environment. The newer Standard logic apps can run in Azure but they can also be deployed locally in your development environment, running on the Functions runtime. This means that you can write logic app unit tests in the same way that you would with a C# function and run the tests locally. You could also run the same tests as part of a CI/CD pipeline in Azure DevOps or GitHub actions.

Standard logic apps do not include any unit testing framework to help with the creation of tests, but check out the [LogicAppUnit](https://github.com/LogicAppUnit/TestingFramework) test framework which fills this gap.